# Importing to mysql from a .gz via shell - how to do it without extracting to a file?

Tags: unix, zip, tar, gz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pipe gunzip and mysql to gunzip a dump and import it](https://superuser.com/questions/402371/pipe-gunzip-and-mysql-to-gunzip-a-dump-and-import-it)

i have a .gz file of an sql dump. at the moment i extract it to its own file (ie dump.sql.gz extracted to dump.sql) then i import that file, then once its done i delete the file.

how can i just import without having to make / delete the sql file?

(im on unix btw)

Answer (score 4):

If the import tool can read from a pipe you could use [zcat](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/zcat/)

> $> zcat dump.sql.gz | import_tool

Comment: +1 for k.i.s.s. principle :).  note zcat's usually a shellscript that exec's `gzip -cd` (meaning `gzip --stdout --decompress`)