# Pipe gunzip and mysql to gunzip a dump and import it

Tags: mysql, pipe, dump, stdout, gunzip

I have a .gz sql dump file (example: foo.sql.gz) that i want import in my database with the classic mysql command.

```
gunzip -c foo.sql.gz > foo.sql

mysql -uroot -ppassword foo < foo.sql
```

foo is the database.

How can i pipe these two commands in a single one?

Tried

```
gunzip -c foo.sql.gz | mysql -uroot -ppassword foo
```

but doesn't seem to work; i get `gzip: stdout: Broken pipe`

Comment: FYI you really do not want to pass the mysql password on the command line.  This leads to it being stored in ~/.bash_history for all to see.  If you just put -p it will prompt you to enter your password which is much safer (and doesn't break the zcat pipe either)

Comment: You orignal command would work if gunzip < foo.sql.gz | mysql -uroot -ppassword foo

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
zcat foo.sql.gz | mysql -uroot -ppassword foo
```

This will also leave `foo.sql.gz` as it is.

Comment: In terms of speed this works much more slower than gunzip && mysql -e "use unzipped.sql".

Answer (score 14):

For those on Max OSX there is [a bug](http://od-eon.com/blogs/calvin/zcat-bug-mac-osx/) with `zcat` so you'll need to use `gzcat` instead.

```
gzcat foo.sql.gz | mysql -uroot -ppassword foo
```

Answer (score 9):

All other answers are recommending writing the password in the command. This is a very bad practice and poses security risks. Please **DON'T DO** that.

You can leave the password empty in the command, than it will ask you to enter the password interactively. This way the password is not saved in the bash history.

```
gunzip < dump.sql.gz | mysql -u username -p databasename
```

Comment: this is the answer i was looking for